# Passing a (I think) valid object in swift but getting a found nil while unwrapping optional error

Tags: ios, swift

Dear stackoverflow helpers. I am working on a swift ios project and am having problems with these two functions in a library I am using. When passing `m` to `self.socket.send()` I get a **"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** error. This is strange to me as when I print to object I get this:

`print(m) = {
    "id":"84e7D4B9825D4Da8a8f47e7f5e31DA9d",
    "method":"pinCodes.validate",
    "msg":"method",
    "params":[{"code":"1"}]
}`

The code breaks on the line self.socket.send(m)

Help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
if let m = message.stringValue(){
        print("sending message")
        print(m)
        self.socket.send(m)
 }

 open func send(_ message : Any){
    print("Message is")
    print(message)
    if !opened{
        return
    }
    ws.send(message)
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: Debug which line is giving you this error. Than you will probably find the answer yourself. If not, let us know.

Comment: And why do you attempt to safely unwrap `message.stringValue()` as an `Any?` ? The point of safe unwrapping is to eliminate the conditional. So using `Any?` instead of `Any` makes no sense.

Comment: I have found the line that the code breaks on and the point of this question is that I have no clue why it is not working. It breaks when passing m to send()

Comment: How is you stringValue() defined ?

Comment: String value is func stringValue() -> String? {
        if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
            return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
        return nil
    }

Comment: So it seems likely that `self.socket` is nil